# Multiplus dominio com Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho uma hospedagem com dois domínios, dominio1.com.br e dominio2.com.br.

Como o Codeigniter esta na raiz da hospedagem, como faço para que, quando
eu acessar o dominio1.com.br ele pegue o conteudo da pasta site1 e exiba, e faça
a mesma coisa no dominio2.com.br e exiba o conteudo da pasta site2 em que se misture?

Não sei se é possível fazer isso no .htaccess

Eu gostaria de aproveitar a mesma hospedagem para 2 sites diferentes com domínios diferentes sem ter que comprar uma hospedagem para cada site.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso usando o .htaccess. Depois você precisa tratar isso no Code Igniter.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on

#
# Redirecionando o domínio para a pasta correta
#
# Regra para cada domínio, copie e adapte para cada domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pastadominio1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pastadominio1/$1

#
# Removendo /pastadominio1/index.php da URL
#
# Regra para cada domínio, copie e adapte para cada domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pastadominio1/index.php
```